# Error 500 (RuntimeError) when refetching data with axios and nuxtjs

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, headless

I built a blog based page with wordpress as api and nuxtjs as javascript framework.
The problem happens in my _slug.vue. When I navigate to a single blog (project) post the single post is rendered normally. But if I reload the single post page or when I just type in the url I get an error in the console: GET *url* 500 (RuntimeError).

```
<template> 
<div class="single-project">
    <Header />
    <h1>{{project.title.rendered}}</h1>
    <article v-html="project.content.rendered"></article>
    <ClickToAction />
</div>
```

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import axios from 'axios'
export default{
    data() {
        return {
            project: {}
        }
    },
    async asyncData({params}){

            return await axios.get('https://my-api.wp/wp-json/wp/v2/project/' + params.id)
                .then((res) => {
                    return {
                        project: res.data
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    if (error.response) {
                    // Request made and server responded
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                    console.log(error.response.status);
                    console.log(error.response.headers);
                    } else if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    console.log(error.request);
                    } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                    }
                });
    }
}
</script>
```

and the link to one project:

```
<nuxt-link :class="'item ' + project._embedded['wp:term'][0].map(el => el.name.toLowerCase()).join(' ')" v-for="project in projects"  :key="project.id" :to="{name: 'projekte-slug', params: { slug: project.slug, id: project.id}}">
```

target is static in the nuxt.config.js

## **EDIT**

After research I found out that the id which is passed in the nuxt-link params object gets lost after reloading because it needs the "parent" page to get the value of id. To fix this I fetched the project with the slug which is always contained in the url project/:slug by api and displayed all the properties (e.g title, content, ...)

```
async asyncData({ params, $axios }) {
        try {
            console.log(params.slug);
            const project = await $axios.$get(`https://my-api.wp/wp-json/wp/v2/project?slug=${params.slug}&_embed`)
            return { project }
        } catch (error) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`asyncData` is not re-triggered when you refresh the page or type the URL directly.
If you want to fetch the data upon those events, either use the [`fetch()` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook) or a [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware).

---

##### Edited answer

Be sure that you've installed `@nuxtjs/axios` before proceeding any further: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

```html
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, $axios }) {
    try {
      const project = await $axios.$get(`https://my-api.wp/wp-json/wp/v2/project/${params.id}`)
      return { project }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        // Request made and server responded
        console.log(error.response.data)
        console.log(error.response.status)
        console.log(error.response.headers)
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        console.log(error.request)
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log('Error', error.message)
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? I'm using `asyncData` everywhere and don't have any troubles with page reloads

Comment: @tho-masn The reference is in the documentation: `Unlike fetch, the promise returned by the asyncData hook is resolved during route transition.` You can simply use a `console.log` there to see if it's triggered. Not sure how your app works as a whole but this is how it works so far. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data

Comment: Yes, but this means, `asyncData` allows blocking rendering, as long as the returned Promise isn't resolved. `fetch` doesn't allow you to do this,  but you have the pending states instead, which you don't have with `asyncData`. However, it doesn't mean that `asyncData` is not executed on page loads.

Comment: @tho-masn damn, you're right.. Always thought it was not triggered upon a hard refresh. Hm...I maybe failed something, damn my bad! So, I've edited my answer, try this syntax and see if it works better.

Comment: @kissu thanks for the answer but still got the same error after reloading the page on localhost. when i deploy the site I get another error (404): 
GET https://my-api.wp/wp-json/wp/v2/project/undefined 404. 
seems like the id is undefined on reload... you guys have any idea for this?

Comment: What is logged, when you `console.log(params)`?

Comment: with console.log(params) I only get the slug of the project but not the id. I don't see the reason why it's only passing the slug after reload...

Comment: What is your file structure and the URL you're reaching here? @nip

Comment: @kissu added the file structure to main thread on top. 
the url of a single post: localhost/projekte/SLUG
the content comes from wordpress: my-api.wp/wp-json/wp/v2/project/ID.